# How to add Different Images to Annotations in same Map View

Tags: iphone, annotations, mkmapview, mkannotation, mapkit

I have A MapView with Multiple annotations. But I need to put different images to annotations according to JSON value.

[image]

This is what I want to do... Need to add Different Images to pins according to the JSON value.

is there any one has a idea how to do that? Please help and that would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the delegate method:

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation

and according to your JSON values you can set the image:
 The below is my sample code:

```
UIImage * flagImage = nil;

if(Your JSON Values)
flagImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"darkgreendot.png"];
else if(....)
flagImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"orangedot.png"];
else
flagImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bluedot.png"];

CGRect resizeRect;  
        resizeRect.size = flagImage.size;   
        resizeRect.origin = (CGPoint){0.0f, 0.0f};
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(resizeRect.size);
        [flagImage drawInRect:resizeRect];
        UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
        annotationView.image = resizedImage;
```

Answer (score -2):

in the

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

delegate just set image to your annotation view

```
annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"crazyPin.png"];
```

Comment: If some one just down voted my answer it will be nice to comment why my answer is not good.